# How do I retrieve the text a user has typed into the terminal (but before the user has pressed enter)

Tags: python, bash

I am writing a program that will run in the background of a bash terminal.  I would like to be able to read the text that the user has typed (or pasted) into the terminal.

Example:

```
user@host:~/Documents/Code$ grep -rli whatever ./
```

Lets say the user has typed some things into bash *but has not yet pressed enter* (as shown above).

Is there any way to read the input buffer to obtain the text that is currently sitting in the input buffer? In this example I would want to be able to read `"grep -rli whatever ./"`. After the user presses enter and a new prompt is displayed, this method should return the empty string.

I have thought about grabbing keystrokes but this won't detect all forms of input (for example if the user uses copy/past, presses tab for autocomplete, or uses the arrow keys to bring up a previous command).

My preferred interface for doing this is python, but if anybody knows of a solution in any other language I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: I think you need to implement your own shell (which is not terribly hard in Python) to do this because your process can't read the command line if it's not running yet.

Comment: You could probably do this, with the  `ncurses` library, or similar. A Python binding for ncurses does exist,  but  you still have to figure out *where* the user is typing.

Comment: Actually, I think copy-paste is simulated in Unix shells, by sending keystrokes to the program running in the terminal. (Copy-paste didn't exist in *real* terminals, such as a`VT100` serial connection.)

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2063457/712526) an answer that might help.

Comment: You might also be able to use an [`expect`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/expect) script, but I don't know nearly enough about `expect` to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it at arbitrary times, but bash (and other shells) allow extensibility in their completion function, so you can read what the command line says when a tab is pressed for autocompletion: http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/04/writing-your-own-bash-completion.html